# Karabiner: screen flashes when I hit shift-ctrl-opt-cmd-W

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, screen, karabiner

I use Karabiner to map my capslock key to a "hyper" key, namely the combination of [buckybits](http://catb.org/jargon/html/B/bucky-bits.html) in the title, which I map to "word wrap" in a few applications.  This key works fine, but as a side effect, the whole screen flashes white, as if I had the "screen flash" accessibility setting enabled, or as if I had taken a screenshot (no screenshot appears to have been taken though).  It's just this one key combination that triggers the flash, no matter where I hit it (ie. the effect is global).

I'm very well aware of other questions here where the issue was due to just that, the `Preferences > Accessibility > Audio > Flash the screen (etc)` being enabled, but I've verified that it's not enabled.  It does appear related to Karabiner itself, because the effect stops when I quit Karabiner.  I've searched through my Karabiner config however, and found nothing that would produce this behavior.

So the question is, where is this screen flash behavior coming from?  It seems a harmless effect, but I'm curious nonetheless.

Comment: This is driving me bonkers. Anyone else have a recommendation?

Comment: Having the same issue. The problem doesn't go away when you close Karabiner though, you just have to press `shift+ctrl+cmd+opt+W` ***manually*** and the screen still flashes; which would point to it being an undocumented Mac OS shortcut. Not sure whether that's more or less annoying, haha. Found some more info on this! https://groups.google.com/g/osx-karabiner/c/MtFX52RlMVE/m/FUASpFHSAQAJ Turns out it's the shortcut for running wifi/system diagnostics on Catalina OS?